# Design view same DP and size as Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

Why does Google make it so difficult to use the same width and height as my emulator? I can't find a way to actually get the same screen size and dp as my emulator on the design view. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what your issue is. If you mean the visual designer of Android Studio, you can specify *exactly* which Device, Theme, etc. you want:

[image: Image of Android Studio Visual Designer with the drop down menu to select a device opened, displaying various devices]

Comment: I have a physical tablet and an emulator, these both have the same screen size and dp. But in the design view where you can add stuff, It's not the same, so when I try to update the app, all the stuff I have added don't align. And the tablet and emulator are not in the Virtual Device tab you are showing. BTW it's an 8 inch by 800 x 1280 resolution and 534 x 584 dp